# How to get `https` invoke_url from `aws_apigatewayv2_stage`?

Tags: terraform

I am using api gateway v2 for https API in `Terraform` followed this instruction: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/apigatewayv2_stage.html.

However, the invoke URL in the output is always returns `wss://xxx`. How can I get `https://` url in the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
replace("wss://xxx", "wss://", "https://")
```

so your output will be:

```
output "example_output" {
  value = replace(aws_apigatewayv2_stage.example.invoke_url, "wss://", "https://")
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a working solution. Is there a native support for that? I don't want to put this logic on my terraform. It is weird that the it always output `wss://` protocol.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no output that is returning value that you are looking for.